# How to write mysql subquery in Knex?

Tags: mysql, subquery, knex.js, koa

I am trying to write mysql subquery sql in knex but the results of query are undesired.

This is my MySQL query:

```
    select *
    from istifta
    where istifta_id not in (
    select istifta_id
    from status
    where status = 'divided'
    )
```

This is my query converted to Knex:

```
    subquery = await ctx.knex
      .select('istifta_id')
      .from('status')
      .where('status', 'divided')

    result = await ctx.knex
    .select()
    .from('istifta')
    .where('istifta_id', 'not in', subquery)
```

MySQL query is returning two rows all of which doesn't have `status = 'divided'`
While Knex is returning three rows with a row having `status = 'divided'`

Comment: There is no need to add `await` for the subquery. And I guess it won't even work that way. While awaiting you are waiting for the promise to be resolved and get an array of objects and executing 2 queries this way. While not awaiting you have a knex builder for a subquery instead of result and thus 1 query executed with a subquery instead of 2 separate queries. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.whereNotIn`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereNotIn) together with the function() definition option to nest your subquery. Your subquery is inside of the function() as:

```
 select('istifta_id').from('status').where('status', 'divided')
```

and the `.on` functions just make debugging a bit easier.

```
result = await ctx.knex.from('istifta')
    .whereNotIn( 'istifta_id', function() {
        this.select('istifta_id').from('status').where('status', 'divided')
    })
    .on('query', function(data) { 
        console.log("TEST001 data:", data); })
    .on('query-error', function(ex, obj) {
        console.error("TEST002 KNEX query-error ex:", ex, "obj:", obj);
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. One question just.. Do you see anything wrong with my posted code in question? If not then why its not working. I used the way that is often mentioned in KnexJS documentation.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the query in your Question.